# how to inspect hidden element bootstrap css class

Tags: html, css

I have this simple bootstrap navigation menu. While inspecting the element using Google chrome browser I found that one of the class is applied on a list element is not displayed in Styles window of chrome  browser. I was wondering if this could be from one of the external stylessheets but after spending hours I could not find it.

```html
<nav class="nav-menu float-right d-none d-lg-block">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html" class="btn-get">Home</a></li>
   <li class="drop-down"><a href="about.html" class="btn-get">About</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="" class="btn-get">About 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="btn-get">About 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="services.html" class="btn-get">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html" class="btn-get">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I can see "drop-down" class after inspecting element in Elements window but not in Styles window where we can see applied styles. please explain why and how is this happening?.

**Edit v1**

Inspecting Element in Desktop version

[image]

Inspecting Element in Mobile version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drop down is a class used in bootstrap by the JavaScript included in bootstrap. It creates the drop down effect utilizing JS and not css.

Comment: is there any way to inspect that element class which is utilizing JS and remove or hide it temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `drop-down` is not a Bootstrap CSS class but rather a class which is utilised by the Bootstrap javascript to create the drop-down effect.
Further, if a class does not exist in the stylesheets, it will show up on the elements tab but not in the **styles** window.

Also, according to me, you are not implementing dropdown in a proper way as documented in [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).
Here is a small example of dropdown:

```js
$(".toggle-hover").on("mouseenter", function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("show")) {
        $(this).click();
    }
});
$(".toggle-hover").parent().on("mouseleave", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")){
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Example Start -->
    <!-- Example single danger button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle toggle-hover" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Example End-->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Though I believe I answered your question in the first half itself, I included the piece so you can verify.

Comment: Also, Open Inspect, Click on :hov so then you can inspect some more actions

Comment: Ya, you are right! But that does not apply to classes which are not present in the stylesheet(s) since they are not visible in `Styles` window. But yes, clicking on :hov in filters of styles window gives a lots of options.

Comment: It will, once you trigger the state, it will activate the state from js. like when you hover, or active etc. and you can add css to it by creating a class on it and saving it in the css file.

Comment: enabling :hov on that drop-down class doesn't show drop-down class properties in styles. And how can inspect element class if it is not in style-sheet but coming from js file on trigger event?  Second, the example you given here is not on hover dropdown, I specially needed on hover dropdown.

Comment: @trojanatwar enabling `:hov`  and then selecting `hover` fires the necessary js event trigger. And I added the hover functionality by adding a bit of javascript. Pls check it out .

Comment: @MohammedBilal I got your point. But in your example we can clearly see js script by inspecting element and it will appear in styles window. I read Bootstrap all classes here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp I did not find any class name "drop-down" but "dropdown". FYI I took that navbar code from here https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Mamba/ you can go inspect "drop-down" class.

Comment: @trojanatwar "drop-down" is probably used by JS to hook on an Event Listener and not to provide any style which is the reason why it does not appear in `styles` window

Comment: @MohammedBilal Then, how can I see CSS properties of "drop-down" class?

Comment: @trojanatwar there aren't any properties related to `drop-down` class..... most probably

Comment: You sure you did not find **<li class="drop-down">** class ?  @trojanatwar

Comment: @MohammedBilal Nope. I did not. But thing is that "drop-down" class, I want to remove it in mobile view and removing it by display: none using media query it removes whole nav-menu. So thats why I want to inspect "drop-down" class to see whats in it.

Comment: I wish i could post a meme here..... :| @trojanatwar Youre saying you did not find the `drop-down` class? did you right click on the **Drop Down** word in ur template and inspect?

Comment: @MohammedBilal I think what I've mentioned above is clearly you didn't get it, did you?.
If I would have seen by doing "Right click on the Drop Down word in my template ans inspect" then I never would have posted this issue. You can see screenshot above in edited version and tell me do you see any "drop-down" class in inspecting window?.

Comment: @trojanatwar You are almost there, just like you posted in your screenshot, click the `+` button now to add the css class on drop-down, Copy it and save it into css file and it will work as you style.